# Verify PDF digital signature

Tags: itext, digital-signature

I am building a restful service that verify digital signature, Is there a way to verify without sending the whole PDF file to the service ?

Comment: You should explain a bit more. Obviously it is possible to verify a PDF signature without sending the whole PDF to your service, for example by not using your service at all but doing all the verification locally. But that surely is not what's on your mind. Thus, you should explain what role in all this your service shall have and how complicated and security-related code clients of your service shall have to implement on their side. Or are you going to provide a client library, too, that extracts the needed data from the PDF and forwards that data to your service for validation? ...

Comment: Furthermore, what kinds of PDF signatures do you want to verify? Merely the good ol' pure ISO 32000-1 style signatures? Or do you also want to support the additional extras from ISO 32000-2 / ETSI EN 319 142-1?

Comment: @mkl, Thanks for your reply. The service is a multi tenant so it will be used by multiple clients and I don't want to deploy the service by each client. And some clients reject to send the PDF file to the service so is there any solution to send the needed data only (without deploy something at the client side )

Comment: *"without deploy something at the client side"* - well, obviously there is a need for some code on the client side, a PDF does not spontaneously fall apart into signature container and hash of signed bytes. And that's only the parts in case of a simple signature of the good ol' type... That being said, what kind of service are you talking about? REST? SOAP? Or do you actually mean some web page for human users?

Comment: Restful service will be integrated with multiple client. The signature type is Cades basic

Comment: Ok, so the clients access you in an automatized manner. Thus, they are going to do some programming anyways. Or at least should be prepared to do so. Then they indeed can use iText or similar libraries for their programming environment to implement the part of PDF signature verification on their side that extracts signatures, timestamps, and validation related information and calculates hashes over the related signed byte ranges. In particular if the mentioned extras from ISO 32000-2 / ETSI EN 319 142-1 shall be supported, that can mean quite a lot of work, though.

Comment: Thanks @mkl for your response

Comment: One remark, though: If you make your clients implement so much stuff themselves that requires in-depth knowledge on the topic in question (in particular if the mentioned extras from ISO 32000-2 / ETSI EN 319 142-1 shall be supported, they do need to know a lot), they'll wonder why they need you at all and eventually switch to implementing the last mile (the CMS signature container validation) all by themselves, too.

Comment: @mkl Could I get your advice on a related issue on PDF signature verification ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74415723/nodejs-how-to-verify-pdf-signature-of-algorithm-sha256withrsaencryption @mkl

Comment: @Morris *"Could I get your advice on a related issue on PDF signature verification ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74415723/nodejs-how-to-verify-pdf-signature-of-algorithm-sha256withrsaencryption"* - unfortunately i don't know the js libraries involved. At first glance, though, it looks like the code is confronted with a type of signature it doesn't know, maybe there is an error in the pdf? Can you share the signed document?

Comment: @mkl Sure. I invited your github to https://github.com/air-share/pdf-verify-personal-pdf/issues/1 where we can continue a conversation