# nodejs How to verify PDF signature of algorithm sha256withRSAencryption?

Tags: node.js, pdf, cryptography, digital-signature

While using npm lib `@ninja-labs/verify-pdf` I got

```
node_modules/node-forge/lib/asn1.js:670
for(var i = 0; i < obj.value.length; ++i) {
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Object.asn1.toDer ...
```

Related sample code https://github.com/air-share/pdf-err-demo

By inspecting the lib source code, I confirmed that my PDF was signed via algorithm `sha256withRSAencryption`, but the lib only supports ['md5', 'sha256', 'sha1', 'sha512', 'sha384', 'sha512/256', 'sha512/224']

Could someone give some advice on:
How would I verify such a PDF signature?
What other experts / resources to investigate?
Is it a good idea to verify the signature via node native module `crypto` with something like

```
crypto.verify(
    "sha256WithRSAEncryption",
    signedData,
    pubKeyString,
    Buffer.from(signature, "binary")
  );
```

?
If yes, how would I parse out these 3 items from a given PDF?

```
signedData,
pubKeyString,
signature
```

Comment: The embedded signature container is defect. In places where it should have algorithm identifiers for hash algorithms, it has identifiers for signature algorithms. Any sensible validator should reject this signature.

Comment: @mkl Was your comment based on the PDF I shared? Windows/Mac Adobe PDF Reader and Linux LibreOffice all consider it "valid". Were they just being lenient?

Comment: *"Was your comment based on the PDF I shared?"* - yes.  *"Windows/Mac Adobe PDF Reader and Linux LibreOffice all consider it "valid". Were they just being lenient?"* - indeed. Acrobat is known to be very lenient in regard to information in the signature container. LibreOffice appears to follow that example.